# importing css to scss not working in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am trying to add package `css` file into my `app.scss` but it doesn't work,

## Code

**app.scss**

```
@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4.css';
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

when I run `npm run watch` it works successfully but the style doesn't add to `app.css`

any idea?

## Update

this is my complete `app.scss` file

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4';



.navbar-laravel {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

when I use `@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4';` and run `npm run watch` command I get:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                  22:53:58
 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot' in
```

but if i use `@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4.css';` and run `npm run watch` it doesn't show any error and also **will not mix my css file** with the rest of them.

Comment: Is the css file path wrong? You can try add a simple file, the path is same with app.scss.

Comment: @lighter no `~` will get `node_modules` folder

Comment: I use this `// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";`. It's work for me.

Comment: @lighter updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since webpack is correctly resolving `@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4.css';` without splitting out a 'css-loader' error, it's likely you need to burst your browser cache.

You can fix this by versioning your compiled assets. Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting).

1. Make these changes in the `webpack.mix.js` file to turn on versioning.

   `mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();`
2. Now run `npm run watch` again.

   This will result in a new file `mix-manifest.json` being created under the public folder.
3. Then modify your blade template as follows

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">
   <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this to work by removing the extension from the path:

```
@import '~tjdbs4/tjdb4';
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, i updated my question.

Comment: @mafortis If you run `npm run dev` from a new tab, wait for it to finish and then scroll back up, can you confirm there are definitely no errors? Is this a public or private package by the way?

Comment: definitely no error https://ibb.co/iYPXEp , so far is public. https://www.npmjs.com/package/tjdbs4

Answer (score 0):

Your error seemed to be an issue with `FontAwesome` fonts and specifically the brands icon set from them.

---

This whole chunk here in `app.scss`

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
```

should be placed inside your main js file like the following

---

Example

**app.js**

```
import brands from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands'
import regular from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular'
import solid from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid'
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'

fontawesome.library.add(brands)
fontawesome.library.add(regular)
fontawesome.library.add(solid)
```

Comment: @mafortis you are missing a from

Comment: I realized that and tried with different ways it seems is not allowed to be in app.js file as they are styles they must be load in app.scss file

Comment: What is the error? I personally am importing FontAwesome into `.js` file and it worked

Comment: Hold up, I see something potentially wrong with the package path. Let me confirm that and get back to you

Comment: The error refers to imported files as i shared image. Ps: for other ways i tried errors almost same

Comment: See the latest changes that I have made.